# How to find probability of total amount of time of multiple events being less than x when you know distribution of individual event times?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

An event has a known distribution of completion times, and is repeated n times.

How would you calculate the probability of the total time being less than or equal to a specified time.

$$P((Time_1 + Time_2 + ... + Time_n)\leq X)$$

For example say that each event's time is exponentially distributed with an expected rate of 1.25 minutes per event, and you want to find the probability of completing the task 400 times in less than or equal to 500 minutes. The events are completed consecutively, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, calculating the distribution of the sum of a bunch of random variables is not simple. Normally (pun intended ;-), we rely on [known results from mathematical statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions#:%7E:text=The%20sum%20of%20n%20exponential,with%20N%20degrees%20of%20freedom.).

For examples:

1. The sum of normally distributed random variables is also normally distributed.
2. The sum of Poisson distributed random variables is also Poisson
3. The sum of binomial random variables is binomial if they have the same value for $P(X=1)$

In your case, if the times are exponentially distributed then

> The sum of $n$ independent exponential$(\beta)$ random variables is a
> gamma$(n, \beta)$ random variable.